# How to load a color theme correctly in IDAPro?

Tags: ida, idapython, ida-plugin

I work late nights and a dark theme [like this](https://github.com/zyantific/IDASkins) would be nice with IDAPro.

I followed the installation steps and copied the contents of 'plugins' from the github page to the 'plugins' directory in my IDAPro folder in C:/

Then, I went to `options` > `colors` > `import` and imported the `.clr` file. But it only changes the color scheme for the disassembly window. Everything else is still the default theme (see image attached). I searched the web looking for if there's something I'm missing but no luck. Seems like I'm doing everything correctly.

Is there anything I'm missing? How can I get the theme to propagate all over IDAPro 7.0?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're talking about changing the appearance of Qt widgets and not only IDA widgets. If so, take a look at [zyantific/IDASkins](https://github.com/zyantific/IDASkins) python plugin.
There're also plugins in C++ if you prefer it.

Comment: I linked that same link in my original question. I did try the procedure at that page (copy contents of the plugins directory) but it does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry about it. Can you see '[IDASkins] v2.0.4 by athre0z (zyantific.com) loaded!' in the 'Output window' when you start IDA?

Comment: No I cannot see that in the output window. It shows that the database of the binary I'm analyzing is loaded but that's about it. Is there a way to explicitly load IDASkins into IDA?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have a file named ``idaskins.py`` in your plugins folder? Otherwise, you can try to type ``from idaskins.plugin import IdaSkinsPlugin`` from the Python widget.

Comment: I checked and I cannot find the Python Widget. I am also running the free version of IDAPro 7. Is it not possible to load these in the free version of IDA?

Comment: IDA Free does not have IDAPython so no

Answer (score 0):

To get complete dark theme you must use IDASkins and Ida Consonance
[image]

If you're using IDA 6.5 - > 6.9 you will need [IDASkins 1.4.1](https://github.com/zyantific/IDASkins/releases/download/v1.4.1/release-1.4.1.zip)

For all versions of IDA you can use the same ida-consonance version for the code blocks and highlighting.

**Install [IDASkins](https://github.com/zyantific/IDASkins) first:**

1. Copy IDASkins.p64 & IDASkins.plw into the IDA plugins folder
2. Open IDA Pro
3. Edit -> Plugins -> IDA Skins: Settings
4. Select IDASkins dark -> Click OK

**Then install [ida consonance](https://github.com/eugeneching/ida-consonance):**

1. Copy ida-consonance.clr into the ida directory, wherever
2. Open IDA Pro
3. Options -> Colors -> Import
4. Navigate to IDA root directory\skin\
5. Select ida-consonance.clr and open
6. Click Ok
7. Close & re-open IDA Pro

For IDA 7.0+ IDASkins has been migrated to a IDAPython plugin which is different than the .p64 and .plw type plugins. You have to build it yourself and you need IDA Python installed.   But you can still use ida consonance on 7.0+ and that portion still works fine.

For IDA 7.3 IDASkins is deprecated, 7.3 has built in theme support

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following: download the plugins dll to have the ida skins plugin after copying the files to the plugins folder
Dowload : https://github.com/zyantific/IDASkins/releases/tag/v1.4.1

'C: \ Program Files \ IDA 7.5 \ plugins'

[[image: DLL]

when you start going you will go to

[image]

you need to have the skins folder in the main directory of your way with all the styles

All of the above mentioning in the next blog
https://aaaddr.wordpress.com/2018/01/09/ida-%E7%A5%9E%E5%99%A8%E6%B7%B1%E8%89%B2%E4%B8%BB%E9%A1%8C%E5%A5%97%E7%94%A8%E6%95%99%E5%AD%B8%EF%BC%8C%E5%BF%AB%E8%AE%93%E4%BD%A0%E7%9A%84-ida-%E6%BD%AE%E5%88%B0%E5%87%BA%E6%B0%B4%E5%90%A7%EF%BC%81/